# Need to make gridview column header into hyperlinks

Tags: gridview, hyperlink, header

How to change the grid view column headers titles to a hyperlink that will get the column name or caption as an argument?

I am dynamically loading the columns from a database. Number of columns will change from DB extraction to DB extraction.

All "column names "colname1, colname2, ..., colnameN" are hyperlinks to a
page w/c will use the column name:

```
[colname1][colname2]....[colnameN]     
[data 1,1 ][data 1,2 ]....[data 1,n ]         
[data 2,1 ][data 2,2 ]....[data 2,n ]
...

[data m,1 ][data m,2 ]....[data m,n ]
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule for GridViews, use the [**`Templates`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx) to customize it.

For Customizing the Header, use the `<headertemplate>` as seen below:

```
<asp:gridview id="AuthorsGridView" runat="server">
<columns>
     <asp:templatefield>            
              <itemtemplate>
                  <%#Eval("First_Name")%> // Example Fields/Columns
                  <%#Eval("_Last_Name")%> // Example Fields/Columns
              </itemtemplate>
      <Headertemplate>         
            <!-- Using a Link button -->
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonEmpName" runat="server" 
                 Text="Employee Name" CommandName="Sort" 
                  CommandArgument="Employees">
             </asp:LinkButton>
      </Headertemplate>
   </asp:templatefield>                      
</columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

You can handle the [**`OnRowCommand`**](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/07/12/sorting-gridview-manually-with-templatefields.aspx) event of GridView whenever the Header is clicked and perform your logic.